# Why does component's property binding with hardcoded string keeps coming up undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component called "myComponent" (drop down button) that I would like to use in two places. First in the navigation and then in the side nav when in mobile view. I need to however, change the image inside the component depending on if it is being displayed from the navigation bar or if it is displayed form side nav.

I am using `@Input() imgName: string = "imageOne"` inside the myComponent.
In the HTML template of the component I interpolate the variable `<img ...src="../{imageOne}.png"`

When I render `<app-my-component [imgName]="imageTwo"></app-my-component>` from navigation component and log the value of imgName is undefined. Can anyone tell me why?

[image]

```
`export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() public imgName: string = "img_one";  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside ng on init");
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("imgName value is: ${this.imgName}")
  }
}
`
```

How I am rendering my component

`<app-my-component [imgName]="imageTwo"></app-my-component>`

Comment: Are curly brackets double or single in your code? They seem to be single here (`{imageOne}`).

Comment: `src="../../../assets/images/{{imgName}}.png"` I am using two curly braces in my HTML template, but one in the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the property value of `this.imageTwo` which doesn't exist. So the value is `undefined`.

Don't use square brackets if you want a string constant

```
<app-my-component imgName="imageTwo"></app-my-component>
                             ^^^ = will be a string literal
```

Comment: That worked. So to use square brackets? Any other time Im assuming.

Comment: Square brackets means you are passing a variable, not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cgTag's answer:

I would recommend setting your default value also in `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  // moved default value to static property, to prevent duplication
  private static defaultImgName: string = "img_one";

  @Input() public imgName: string = MyComponent.defaultImgName;  

  constructor() {
    // after compiling typescript to javascript,
    // imgName property will actually be populated here
  }

  ngOnChanges(values: SimpleChanges) {
    // please note, that ngOnChanges is not executed,
    // if component is initialized w/o any bindings

    // this will be executed on every change of imgName,
    // so if you need it to be checked only once - you can do that
    // with the method values.imgName.isFirstChange()
    if (values.imgName && values.imgName.currentValue === undefined) {
       this.imgName = MyComponent.defaultImgName;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside ng on init");
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("imgName value is: ${this.imgName}")
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make life a lot easier by just doing `<img ...src="../{{imgName || 'img_one'}}.png">` inside the template instead.

Comment: sure. but imo, it depends on the amount of usage of the component :)